# Sql Server extract string inside a text

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

How i can find the 'azerty' string part inside a field that containing this kind of text:

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(max)

SELECT @s='Num Fourn:FST00100
Ref Fourn:azerty
PU HT:10
Remise(%):
Coef:2

*** Veuillez remplir les infos ci-dessus sans modifier la structure des lignes ***
Exemple:
Num Fourn: FST00100
Ref Fourn: ABC123
PU HT: 5.30
Remise(%): 10+5
Coef: 2.26'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this (depending on your actual data it might be necessary to change the line break from `CHAR(13)` to `CHAR(10)`...

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(max)

SELECT @s='Num Fourn:FST00100
Ref Fourn:azerty
PU HT:10
Remise(%):
Coef:2

*** Veuillez remplir les infos ci-dessus sans modifier la structure des lignes ***
Exemple:
Num Fourn: FST00100
Ref Fourn: ABC123
PU HT: 5.30
Remise(%): 10+5
Coef: 2.26';

DECLARE @pos1 INT=CHARINDEX('Ref Fourn:',@s) + LEN('Ref Fourn:');
DECLARE @pos2 INT=CHARINDEX(CHAR(13),@s,@pos1);

SELECT @pos1 AS PosStart
      ,@pos2 AS PosEnd
      ,LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@s,@pos1,@pos2-@pos1)));
```

Comment: Awesome! clap clap

Answer (score 0):

this will make you happy - I bet!

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(max)

SELECT @s='Num Fourn:FST00100
Ref Fourn:azerty
PU HT:10
Remise(%):
Coef:2

*** Veuillez remplir les infos ci-dessus sans modifier la structure des lignes ***
Exemple:
Num Fourn: FST00100
Ref Fourn: ABC123
PU HT: 5.30
Remise(%): 10+5
Coef: 2.26';

WITH Casted(AsXml) AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(@s,CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),'###LineBreak###')  AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),'###LineBreak###','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)
)
SELECT ln
      ,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(':',ln)>0 THEN LEFT(ln,CHARINDEX(':',ln)-1) ELSE ln END AS FirstPart
      ,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(':',ln)>0 THEN RIGHT(ln,CHARINDEX(':',REVERSE(ln))-1) ELSE ln END AS SecondPart
FROM Casted
CROSS APPLY AsXml.nodes('/x') AS A(x)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(x.value('.','nvarchar(max)')))) AS B(ln)
```

Comment: Wow! This is even better! :-)